# Intel Graphics Issue

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, intel

I installed Ubuntu on my laptop recently.
From the live-usb it runs just fine, but the finished install has graphics issues.
The built in screen is constantly slightly fuzzy, the external screens both work fine.
It affects the whole screen and starts after grub boot menu.
[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ij2z7.jpg)

---

Laptop: msi ge72 6qf apache pro

CPU: 6700HQ

BIOS: E1794IMS.117

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Display Manager: X11

---

I already tried a bunch of things.

- changing resolution and framerate
- bios options:

  - i915.modeset=0
  - i915.i915_enable_rc6=1
  - video=1920x1080-24@60
  - video=VGA-1:1920x1080-24@60
  - acpi=0
  - acpi_osi=linux
  - acpi_backlight=vendor
  - noalpic
- Wayland
- Font tweaks

If i can provide any useful info or improve my question in any way just tell me.

Comment: Are you using Wayland or X11?

Comment: Do `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` to see your current BIOS version, and then go to the MSI web site and see if there's a newer BIOS for your motherboard.

Comment: Your BIOS is current.

Answer (score 0):

Start Gnome Tweaks and check/play with these settings... (scaling should be 1.00)...

[image]

Try using Wayland. At the login screen, select your username, then click on the round icon in the lower-right corner of your screen, and change the selection to "Ubuntu" or "Ubuntu on Wayland" (not "Ubuntu on X11/xorg"). Then continue to log in.

Comment: sorry forgot about that, I already tried Wayland. The problem is already there after grub menu.
Also it cannot be a font problem bc its the whole screen not only the fonts.

Comment: @user3609058 Boot to a Ubuntu Live USB and see if the screen looks any better. Report back.

Comment: as i already mentioned in my post, when i run ubuntu live from usb it works just fine, cristal clear graphics

Comment: @user3609058 Sorry I missed that. How long ago did you install Ubuntu? Have you tried to reinstall it?

Comment: I installed it some time ago and already reinstalled it. I will try with a fresh download now.

Comment: interestingly with the a fresh download i already have the issue on the live CD. I suppose it worked with the version I installed before and I just updated to the non working version during install. I will try to find the last Ubuntu version where it works.

Comment: @user3609058 Are you saying that you had problem when booted to the Live DVD? What version? Earlier you indicated that it worked fine when booted to the Live DVD, but that might have been a different version?

Comment: yes with ubuntu 20 i have the issue but with an earlier version i dont have the issue. i may try to find out which version it is (i dont have the old live dvd anymore) but maybe i will also use another OS than ubuntu

Comment: What video driver, and what version?